# In Android OS 10, how to get all the files in the Download folder?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am working with a Raspberry Pi along with an Android device. The Pi hardware dumps some files in the Download folder of the external storage of the Android device (using MTP). The path is:

`/storage/emulated/0/Download`

I developed an app that reads all the files in this folder dumped by the Pi (having a pre-decided prefix in their name) and processes them. My app works fine for devices running on Android OS 9 and below.

Starting Android 10, and the compulsion to use SAF (aka storage access framework) by next year, I want to upgrade my solution to make it future-proof. Although there are far too many questions and answers on SO around this topic, I haven't been able to find the right solution that fits my requirement.

So here is really what I'm trying to ask: Is it safe to assume that the path mentioned above (`/storage/emulated/0/Download`) will be available to the Pi to dump the files in a device running Android 10? If yes, please suggest a way to read all the files present in that path in Android 10, programmatically? If no, kindly suggest an alternate way to achieve this entire process?

Comment: You might wish to provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are accomplishing: "The Pi hardware dumps some files in the Download folder of the external storage of the Android device". Is this via `adb` or something?

Comment: I have edited the question to include this information. I used MTP to do this.

Comment: "Is it safe to assume that the path mentioned above (/storage/emulated/0/Download) will be available to the Pi to dump the files in a device running Android 10?" -- for an arbitrary Android device? No. "kindly suggest an alternate way to achieve this entire process?" -- have an app on the device that pulls data from the Pi, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CommonsWare. One last question: is there no location in an arbitrary Android device that the Pi could dump files at? Also, the android device must be able to get back the files from this location programmatically.

Comment: "is there no location in an arbitrary Android device that the Pi could dump files at?" -- it is more that you cannot assume a particular filesystem path. `/storage/emulated/0/Download` *may* work, but it may not, particularly for devices with multiple user accounts. To use `/storage/emulated/0/Download`, you need to be willing to say "sorry!" to users where that directory does not exist.